# How to integrate Mailerlite API on my registration form?

Tags: php

I'm a total noob at programming. I'm currently creating a website where a user can register.

**What I want to happen is the following:**

1. When the user registers, he/she will be added to my MailerLite subscriber list.
2. All the information will also be saved to my website's database.

I played around with the MailerLite documentation but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: show what you've actually tried, what doesn't work, etc

Answer (score 0):

I installed all the libraries found here: https://github.com/mailerlite/mailerlite-api-php-v1#installation using composer then I created a php file with this code:

`

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$ML_Subscribers = new MailerLite\Subscribers("*my API*");

$subscriber = array(
    'email' => 'first@example.com',
    'name' => 'First name'
);

$result = $ML_Subscribers->setId( *my GROUP ID* )->add($subscriber);
?>'
```

but it appears to do nothing, once I submit the form, it will load the php file that I created and shows nothing, I check my subscriber list in MailerLite and nothing is added.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what does the script return - add `var_dump($result);` in the end of the file.
And MailerLite doesn't accept "@example.com" emails, so be sure to change this